# Calculate the integral $\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}\frac{1}{(1-xy)^a}dydx$ for $a>0$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm having trouble with the integral $\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}\frac{1}{(1-xy)^a}dydx$ for the case in which $a\neq{1}$. For the case in which $a=1$ it was not difficult to calculate the integral and I got the convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Now, for the case in which $a>0$ and $a\neq{1}$, first, I calculated the integral $\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1-xy)^a}dy$ and by making a change of variable I got the result $\frac{-1}{x}$($\frac{(1-x)^{1-a}}{1-a}$ - $\frac{1}{1-a}$) which can be simplified to $\frac{1-(1-x)^{1-a}}{x(1-a)}$ (I'm almost sure this is right, but if anyone finds my calculation of this integral with respecto to $y$ is wrong, let me know).

So, then I would have to calculate the integral $\int_o^1\frac{1-(1-x)^{1-a}}{x(1-a)}dx$ and this is where I'm stuck. Maybe I should express one of the expressions in the integrand as a series? Or is there any easier approach to the problem? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try a change of variable for $x$ & $y$?

Comment: I would try polar coordinates on the triangle (0,0), (1,0), (1,1).

Comment: You should have to integrate something like $\int (1-\tan \theta)^{1-a} d\theta$ if you do polar coordinates. I'd then  substitute $u=\tan \theta$ and try to get something like the  Beta function. Also, you got to be careful with convergence issues.

Answer (score 1):

Given the integral you have reached,
$$ \frac{1}{1-a}\int_0^1 \frac{1-(1-x)^{1-a}}{x} \, dx, $$
if you substitute $t=1-x$, you obtain
$$ \frac{1}{1-a}\int_0^1 \frac{1-t^{1-a}}{1-t} \, dt = \frac{1}{1-a} H_{1-a},  $$
in fact by the definition of the harmonic numbers for $a<1$. This looks like a cop-out (because it is), but it comes from [one of the ways of defining the digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Integral_representations).